# OpenXml pivot table: how do you read the total and subtotals in order to display them?

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, openxml

I'm trying to create an Excel pivot table entirely from scratch, using OpenXml.

I've successfully created the pivot table itself (created a PivotTable definition, a cache definition, all the cache  records, pivotFields, RowItems, etc. etc.).

But how do I *display* any of the data?  How do I read the PivotTable calculations in order to write these values to cells?

For example:

[image: Example Pivot Table definition and Pivot Table data]

- The "grand total" is $86,631.62.
- Two subtotals are $61,631,12 and $25,000.50

When I look at the XML in `xl\worksheets\sheet2.xml`, these values are all "hard coded" into the cell.

If I'm creating the cell myself (using OpenXml), then how do I "query" these values, letting the Pivot Table calculate them for me?

PS:
I've been using the OpenXml Productivity Tool extensively  ... but it, too, just "hard codes" the totals and subtotals ... without giving any clue how/where the values were actually calculated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use cell formula if you do not want to use EPPlus:

```
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValue.Number);
cell.CellFormula = new CellFormula($"=SUBTOTAL{"109"}{rowName}");

//force full recalculation of the cells
workbookPart.workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
workbookPart.workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationLoad = true;
```

This way you can use every formula through OpenXml to calculate whatever yoe need.

In order to load into DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"..\..\example.xlsx", false))
{

    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
    string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
    Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
    SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
    IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();

    foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAt(0))
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cell));
    }

    foreach (Row row in rows) //this will also include your header row...
    {
        DataRow tempRow = dt.NewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < row.Descendants<Cell>().Count(); i++)
        {
            tempRow[i] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i-1));
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(tempRow);
    }
```

}

Comment: Q: How exactly does `$"=SUBTOTAL{"109"}{rowName}"` (for example) map to something I've defined in the pivot table?

Comment: You need to extract the row through datatable

Comment: +1: Thank you for responding.  Q: Does "rowName" correspond to something in the pivot table?  If so, how do I find it?  Q: What do you mean by "datatable"?  I don't understand :(  The goal here is that I want to use the pivot table's calculations; I don't want to have to recalculate myself.  My question: "Is this possible?  Or do I *have* to compute my own totals and subtotals (independent of the pivot table) in order to populate my cells?"

Comment: Just load the pivot table into DataTable object through DataSet and you have yourself access to the rows, rowName refers to a specific row in the pivot table. The idea is to loop through the rows for the subtotal.

Comment: Q: Could you update your post to explain how one can "load a pivot table into a Data Table" (in OpenXML)?

Comment: Uploaded as requested!

Comment: I definitely appreciate all your help.  But I'm still not clear how to read anything from the PivotTable in OpenXml.  Or if it's even possible.  Your"formula" example: Q: how can I map `rowName` to anything/anywhere in the pivot table.  Your "DataTable" example: in OpenXml, I add the pivot table (the pivot table definition, the cache definition, the cache records, etc etc) to a worksheet ... but never to any corresponding datasheet. 
 AFAIK, there aren't any "pivot table cells" that I can read using `GetCellValue()`. :(